# Sass bootstrap unable to set height of textarea

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have an admin page like this:

```
<div class="admin_page">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <div class="my-form-group">
            <textarea class="my-form-control">{{user}}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my `main.scss` file:

```
.my-form-group {
  @extend .form-group;

  .my-form-control {
    @extend .form-control
  }
}

@import "./admin.scss";
```

This is my `admin.scss`:

```
.admin_page {
  textarea {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

The height of text area is not set.

I tried `<textarea class="my-form-control" style="height:200px">{{user}}</textarea>` and it works.

Why is the sass version not working?

Edit:

this is my heading:

```
    <!--underscore-->
    <script src="/node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>

    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--bootstrap (keep the css although duplicate in bundle, since some may depend on it)-->
    <script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--font-awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!--summernote-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-bs3.css">-->
    <script src="/node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>


    <!--angular-->
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <!--angular-summernote-->
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-summernote/dist/angular-summernote.min.js"></script>

    <!--bundle-->
    <script src="/public/script/bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/style/bundle.css">
```

Note that I imported sass version of bootstrap in main.scss, which means inside bundle I have the bootstrap css. 
The reason I include the original non-sass version bootstrap is for summernote, which depends on bootstrap.

Edit 2: 
I tried the following:

```
.admin_page {
  .my-textarea {
    @extend .my-form-control;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

which has a specificity of 0,0,2,0 (2 classes), it doesnot work

Also this:

```
.admin_page {

  textarea.my-form-control {
    height: 200px
  }
}
```

which has a specificity of 0,0,2,1 (2 classes + 1 element), it works. Why is the previous one not working?

Comment: Hmm...testing that on sassmeister.com works for me.    http://sassmeister.com/gist/647c31e0f92ded8a178c

Comment: @Aarmora can you try it within bootstrap form group?

Comment: Adding the current bootstrap css did stop the 200px.  Seems like it's a css conflict and not a sass issue.  http://sassmeister.com/gist/47b4162486381371b9aa

Comment: In fact, if I place my css at the top of my page, it'll work.  Is your SCSS page being loading before or after your bootstrap css?  http://sassmeister.com/gist/47b4162486381371b9aa

Comment: This is not a Sass problem.  Check the compiled CSS, you either have a specificity or ordering problem.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with the problem?

Comment: @cimmanon no, but bootstrap has both js and css.

Comment: But the JavaScript is not related to the problem, is it?  The problem persists if you remove all of your JavaScript, doesn't it?  So it is just irrelevant noise.

Comment: @cimmanon i wasn't sure if bootstrap js affects it. but it seems to be specificity problem now.

Comment: This is why you narrow things down to the smallest possible amount of code that reproduces the problem.  When you do that, you should be able to see what's causing the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not problem of sass. It is clearly the problem of specificity.

You just need to mention high specificity css. Since you have a class to the textarea, you can do like this:

```
textarea.my-form-control{
     height: 200px;
}
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to understand how specificity works in css.

Comment: why is the specificity of .admin_page textarea not enough? it gotta be more specific than bootstrap i think

Comment: it's working. but can you explain more? I read through the article but still have doubt

Comment: I also tried to create class .my-textarea inside .admin_page, but not working

Comment: @OMGPOP In your edit, the previous one didn't work because there is already style with that specificity. when you applied more specificity. it worked.

Comment: you mean in bootstrap?

Comment: @OMGPOP bootstrap and sass are on css. I was talking about css. I suggest you to know the difference before using them.